# How can I get the database name from a Perl MySQL DBI handle?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I've connected to a MySQL database using Perl DBI.  I would like to find out which database I'm connected to.

I don't think I can use:

```
$dbh->{Name}
```

because I call [`USE new_database`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html) and `$dbh->{Name}` only reports the database that I initially connected to.

Is there any trick or do I need to keep track of the database name?

Comment: How is it that you connected to a database without knowing what database you were connecting to? You have to pass it to the DBI to setup the connection...

Comment: Perhaps some other module did this for him? Perhaps that other modules decides dynamically what database to use? Perhaps he's just curious?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try just executing the query

```
select DATABASE();
```

From what I could find, the DBH has access to the DSN that you initially connected with, but not after you made the change. (There's probably a better way to switch databases.)

Comment: Yes the query works:

my ($dbname) = $dbh->selectrow_array("select DATABASE()");

Answer (score 4):

`$dbh->{Name}` returns the db name from your db handle.

If you connected to another db after connected with your dbh, using mysql query "USE db_name", and you did not setup a new perl DBI db handle, of course, $dbh->{Name} will return the first you previously connected to... It's not spontaneic generation.

So to get the connected db name once the db handle is set up - for DBI mysql:

```
sub get_dbname {  
    my ($dbh) = @_;  
    my $connected_db = $dbh->{name};  
    $connected_db =~ s/^dbname=([^;].*);host.*$/$1/;  
    return $connected_db;  
}
```

Comment: I think you may want $dbh->{Name}, which is what the DBI docs talk about under "Database Handle Attributes" section.  Also, the DSN will change depending on the driver and even how the user invoked the connect() method.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask mysql:

```
($dbname) = (each %{$dbh->selectrow_hashref("show tables")}) =~ /^Tables_in_(.*)/;
```

Update: obviously select DATABASE() is a better way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a connection object it is for a certain database. In DBI's case anyway.  I I don't believe doing the SQL `USE database_name` will affect your connection instance at all.  Maybe there is a select_db (My DBI is rusty) function for the connection object or you'll have to create a new connection to the new database for the connection instance to properly report it.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - probably not much - DBD::Informix keeps track of the current database, which can change if you do operations such as CREATE DATABASE.  The `$dbh->{Name}` attribute is specified by the DBI spec as the name used when the handle is established.  Consequently, there is an Informix-specific attribute `$dbh->{ix_DatabaseName}` that provides the actual current database name.  See: `perldoc DBD::Informix`.

You could consider requesting the maintainer(s) of DBD::MySQL add a similar attribute.